# jQuery Script to Simulate Hidden Navigation like Facebook App

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

I am creating an iPhone App using HTML/CSS/JS and PhoneGap. I need to create a side menu like the Facebook App has. Somebody knows a good script to create something like that?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will help you :-)

[PageSlide - a jQuery plugin which slides a webpage over to reveal an additional interaction pane](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/)

Comment: Just another update on this. If you are the jQuery Mobile framework then you might also be interested in using the Panel widget. Have a look here for examples: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/panels/